# List of Map of List to MapList Java 8 Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to convert a `List<Map<Integer, List<Object>>>` to a `Map<Integer, List<Object>>` with lambda but I'm totally lost, so far I got this;

```
public Map<Integer, List<Object>> getMapofList(List<Map<Integer, List<Object>>> listMaps) {

    return listMaps
            .stream()
            .filter(listMap -> listMap //Obtained Map
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(integerListEntry -> nonNull(integerListEntry.getValue())) //Check if there is a List<Object> not null
                    . //Not sure how to continue to finally just return a Map<Integer, List<Object>>
}
```

Any hint or help would be much appreciate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one solution would be:

```
return listMaps
        .stream()
        .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet()
                       .stream())
        .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

or if there can be duplicate keys then you can use a `groupingBy` collector like this:

```
return listMaps
         .stream()
         .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet()
                        .stream())
         .filter(e -> e.getValue() != null)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
               Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: this seems good however Map.Entry is invalid "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context". 

Tried that in another way and also got the same. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Dr3ko I am not able to replicate it tbh. although I am running under JDK-9  , IDE - intelliJ IDEA.

Comment: first solution worked very well, not able to use the second solution however thank you, now I understand how to achieve things like the one I asked.